# Flow.min.js not responding

Tags: image-upload, magento1.9.3

After upgrading to Magento 1.9.3 from 1.9.2.4 the product image Uploade button is not working.

When I choose the image and clicks OK the browser just freezes and crashes.
I tried again on Firefox, and gets the message that a script in js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js:2 is not responding.

I run PHP 5.6.27-1 on Ubuntu (So I cant install the html5 upload button from Magento Connect as this does not support over 5.6.25)

EDIT:
It seems that the function can not get the max filesize 
(this.file.size / this.flowObj.opts.chunkSize) in this part of the function the chunkSize is 0 and I believe that is the reason for the crashing

Comment: Seems like the error is in e.prototype.bootstrap function?

Comment: Same problem here. Any solutions?

Comment: @Seb I have found the problem. My max post size was set to "0" (unlimited) but this resulted in a "Divided by zero" error. I changed the limit to a number and restartet PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not found the real problem, but a workaround. De-Minifiy the file /js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js.

Then find the rows

```
bootstrap: function() {
    this.abort(!0), this.error = !1, this._prevProgress = 0;
```

And directly after this add the following line

```
this.flowObj.opts.chunkSize = 1048576;
```

For some reason, the chunkSize is 0 and in the following row the file size is divided by the chunk size. So if chunk size is 0, then this will fail.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks your your answer. You are totally right. I found last night that my post_max_size was set to 0 (Should be unlimited according to the docs). I think the developers should fix this. I Did not try your workaround but looking at it I am sure it would work for those who must have the unlimited post_max_size. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I added the line `this.flowObj.opts.chunkSize = 1048576;` to flow.min.js.
But now I get this error:

[image]

I'm using HHVM on Nginx

Edit: fixed it 
OPEN: /etc/hhvm/php.ini
ADD: hhvm.enable_zend_ini_compat=false

---

Comment: @Julius , Try to edit your php.ini and set upload and post's max sizes above the 1048576. Or just set it to like 1G

Comment: setting hhvm.enable_zend_ini_compat=false worked for me , i had trouble uploading larger files which is also resolved thank a ton