# Failed to upload images in Magento 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento-1.9

Every time I upload an image through Product Add form, I always get this error:

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://domain.com/js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js:2

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: I have the same error http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145279/flow-min-js-not-responding/147688#147688